How to create and link tubes on top of an object without linking it to the object?
I have a stl sculpture that I want to turn into a tubular triangulated wireframe. Is there any way to add points to the surface that I can connect with thick tubes, and then delete the original object? Thank you in advance!!

You can use Mesh to Curve with a Curve Circle as a profile in Geometry nodes, but it will not result in a clean mesh, let alone a 3D printable one. The Wireframe Modifier is also like this but with less control.
